# how to modify built-in classes with Vuejs

Tags: css, vue.js

this is a built-in class in vue-awesome-swiper

```
.swiper-button-next {
   position: absolute;
   right: 46%
}
```

I need to change this CSS code only in right-to-left direction to be like this

```
.swiper-button-next {
   position: absolute;
   left: 46%
}
```

so I have to put a condition , how can I conditionally modify this CSS code

*NOTE* :- I know the condition but I don't know how to apply it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following rule by assuming the `dir="rtl"` attribute is assigned to body element:

```css
body[dir="rtl"] .swiper-button-next {
   left:auto;
   right: 46%;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work with me

Comment: what's the condition that you want to apply?

Comment: i switch the language by option field and store value in local storage and then get that value from local storage and apply my condition on it , if it is rtl language or ltr language , for example if (lang=='ar') then apply the following style .. etc

Comment: Try `document.body.setAttribute('dir', lang === 'ar'?'rtl':'ltr')` then use the rule above

Comment: where to put this piece of code ?

Comment: this should be a replacement of your condition or you could write your condition like `if(lang=="ar"){document.body.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl')} else{document.body.setAttribute('dir', 'ltr')}`

Comment: no  i mean where to put it  in my vuejs component , created or mounted ?

Comment: in mounted or watch

Comment: @MonaShazly u r welcome, please don't forget to accept my answer